# Using Augmented Data Images in Testing

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, face-recognition, pytorch

I am working on a Person Re-Identification problem and am showing the results using a CMC curve.
I used augmented data/Image along with the normal images (Currently training on CUHK01) in the training set. While testing if I don't use the augmented data along with my normal test images for Calculating Rank let's say Rank_1 I get Rank_1 of ~30% on the other hand on using augmented data gives me a Rank_1 of ~65-70% (which is weirdly high regarding the current Rank_1 accuracy in the world).

So my questions are

a) How does augmented data affect the testing set especially in my case.

b) Am I over-fitting or something of that sort.

c) Is it a general rule to avoid usage of augmented images in the test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind using data augmentation is to reduce the chance of overfitting. This way you want to tell your model that the parameters (theta) are not correlated with the data that you are augmenting (alpha). That is achievable by augmenting each input by every possible alpha. But this is far from reality for a number of reasons, e.g. time/memory limitation, you might not be able to construct every possible augmentation, etc. so there might be some bias. Nevertheless, it still reduces the chance of overfitting to your dataset, but it might overfit to your augmentation.

Thus, if you have the augmentation, you might get more accuracy by matching to the augmented data due to the overfitting, which is an answer to question a. So I believe that the answer to the question b is yes.

In order to answer question c, I have not read about rules for data augmentation but in the literature of machine learning I presume that they avoid any augmentation on the test set. e.g. I quote from [a paper](http://gvv.mpi-inf.mpg.de/projects/EgoCap/)

> We augment the training images by
>   replacing the green screen with random background images, and
>   vary the appearance in terms of color and shading by intrinsic recoloring

Comment: Umm I am sorry but i am still not able to get feel of it. On one hand we say data augmentation is good for avoiding over-fitting but then we cant use it for testing case because of over-fitting. Do you or anyone knows any research paper or any source ??  Also my testing case didnt only have augmented data it had combination of both or more like randomly arranged images.

Comment: I think we all agree on the reason of augmenting the training set (which is the generalization of the model). But what should be the reason for augmenting the test set?

Comment: Well Basically i see augmented data more like just more data (although with repeated set of images) and it never hurts does it to do more robust testing to verify your model

Comment: Now since i wrote my last comment i feel like i am getting to the logic behind why not to use the augmented data if i get a true positive case with my image pair lets say [image_a,image_b]  than using augmented data of these cases or something of that sort will just enhance my testing accuracy (maybe cause my model now knows the pattern and is robust to augmented data of images). Do you think my idea or logic seems nice or kind of a decent explanation?? Sorry for wasting your time on these questions

Comment: Seeing the augmented set as a set containing more data is valid as far as the distribution is absolutely random. Say for detecting cats. If you flip the cat images horizontally and no cat images vertically, then your model learns this and recognizes the cats which are horizontally flipped in the test set. This can be resolved only if the augmentation method is unbiased and random.But in reality, it might not be achievable. So just to avoid this bias affect the measure of the accuracy of your model, such generated data better be not there in the test set to avoid affecting the accuracy measure.

Comment: So this is kind of similar to my previous comment right??

Comment: Yes. In your words, the model knows the pattern of your augmentation by which it can classify the image. If that pattern is strong enough as my dummy example, then the pattern makes it much easier for the model to do its job such that it might not even need the actual image features (e.g. cat's face).